# change of variable for indicator function

Tags: calculus, integration

I know that is silly question but how can I change of variable of

$$G(S_t)=1_{S_t\ge K}$$

(where $1_{S_t\ge K}$ are indicator function) with this definition

$$G(e^x)\equiv g(x)$$

then How can I calculate this integral for $R\neq 0$

$$h(u+iR)=\int_\mathbb{R}g(x)e^{ix(u+iR)}dx=\frac{i}{u+iR}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{ix(u+iR)}dg(x)$$

thanks for your help

Comment: What have you tried? And for the integral, try integrating by parts (though I think you're missing a minus sign).

Comment: yeah @mattos I first find $g(x)=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   0 \quad x\ge \ln (K)  \\
   -\infty \quad x<\ln (K)  \\
\end{matrix} \right.$
but in next i got confused .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function should be
$$g(x)=\left\{ \begin{matrix}    1 \quad x\ge \ln (K)  \\    0 \quad x<\ln (K)  \\ \end{matrix} \right.$$

It is then easy to see the integral is from $\ln K$ to $\infty$.